# Tkinter radio button assigning last variable when run?

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button, variable-assignment

I have three files and I am trying to change the value of a variable through radio buttons:

***Config.py***

```
epoch=1
```

***imageClassifier.py***

```
import config
train(args, model, device, train_loader, optimizer, config.epoch)
```

***GUI.py***

```
import config
def changeEpoch(epochValue):
   config.epoch=epochValue

var1 = IntVar()
epochRadioButton1 = Radiobutton(middleFrame, variable=var1, value=1, 
text="1", command=changeEpoch(1))
epochRadioButton5 = Radiobutton(middleFrame, variable=var1, value=2, 
text="5", command=changeEpoch(5))
epochRadioButton10 = Radiobutton(middleFrame, variable=var1, value=3, 
text="10", command=changeEpoch(10))
epochRadioButton20 = Radiobutton(middleFrame, variable=var1, value=4, 
text="20", command=changeEpoch(20))
var1.set(1)
```

However, no matter what, when I run my program, the value of epoch is always 20 and I can't seem to work out why.

Comment: I had the same experience, that Tkinter seemed to default to the last radiobutton used, or all of them if it hasn't been run before. I'm curious to see if someone knows a way to control this differently.

Comment: @NielsHenkens I added 'lambda:' after 'command=' and it seems to have worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this line of code:

```
epochRadioButton20 = Radiobutton(..., command=changeEpoch(20))
```

It has exactly the same effect as this:

```
result = changeEpoch(20)
epochRadioButton20 = Radiobutton(..., command=result)
```

The `command` attribute takes a *callable*. However, your code is immediately calling the function and giving the result to the `command` attribute.

What I recommend is that instead of passing the new value to the function, have the function fetch the value from the radiobutton.  To do so, make the following changes:

```
def changeEpoch():
    epochValue = var1.get()
    config.epoch=epochValue
...
epochRadioButton20 = Radiobutton(..., command=lambda: changeEpoch)
```

Another solution would be to create an anonymous function with `lambda` which calls `changeEpoch` (this assumes you leave `changeEpoch` unmodified):

```
epochRadioButton20 = Radiobutton(..., command=lambda: changeEpoch(20))
```